# Select a grid element from a .map

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a grid and I need to select the fourth element and move from the first column to second column in the row below. I know how to do it in plain html, but not how to select the grid element inside a map.

Here the code:

```
  return (
    <Layout pageTitle='Projects'>
      <GridIndex>
        {data.allMdx.nodes.map((node) => (
          <article key={node.id} className=''>
            <Link to={`/projects/${node.slug}`}>
              <div>{node.frontmatter.title}</div>
              <GatsbyImage
                image={getImage(node.frontmatter.imageCover)}
                alt={node.frontmatter.imageCoverAlt}
                className='h-auto xs:square'
              />
            </Link>
          </article>
        ))}
      </GridIndex>
    </Layout>
  );
};
```

I just need to select the fourth element and put this className:
`className='col-start-2'`

Here an image to understand the problem:
[grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlHH5.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `index` of the map to check if its the 4th iteration.

```
return (
  <Layout pageTitle='Projects'>
    <GridIndex>
      {data.allMdx.nodes.map((node, i) => (
        <article key={node.id} className={i === 3 ? 'col-start-2' : ''}>
        ...
```

Comment: Sure I'll, I just need reputation, I'm new here. Thanks again @a.mola

Answer (score 0):

first of all, you should save the `data.allMdx.nodes` in a state, I'm sure you already know that

then whenever you want to swap some element with another one
you can do this:

```
const swap=()=>{
const tmp=[...listState]
    // here you do the changes to the tmp list
setState(tmp)
}

return (
    <Layout pageTitle='Projects'>
      <GridIndex>
        {state.map((node) => (
          <article key={node.id} className=''>
            <Link to={`/projects/${node.slug}`}>
              <div>{node.frontmatter.title}</div>
              <GatsbyImage
                image={getImage(node.frontmatter.imageCover)}
                alt={node.frontmatter.imageCoverAlt}
                className='h-auto xs:square'
              />
            </Link>
          </article>
        ))}
      </GridIndex>
    </Layout>
 );
```